# (UE4 C++) Converting a data-table row name to a class name to spawn actors

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

so I'm working on a squad-based strategy game like Company of Heroes. I am currently still building a squad framework that the player will interface with and give orders to. I have decided to use data tables to define the contents of squads and units and have run into trouble figuring out how my CreateUnit function will work (which will handle spawning soldiers on the squad actor’s request). I pass two parameters to it, namely the requested class name in the form of an FName taken from the row name of the data table and the amount of that type that must be spawned. I have run into trouble trying to feed that class name variable into the SpawnActor function. This is a slimmed-down version of the relevant code:

```
TArray<FName> ClassNames = ContainerDataTable->GetRowNames();
    
// Call CreateUnit function for every request until squad is full
for (auto& RequestedUnitClass : ClassNames)
    {
    // Select Row
        FUnitContainerData* SelectedRow = ContainerDataTable->FindRow<FUnitContainerData>(RequestedUnitClass, "");
    
        // Find number requested
        int AmountToSpawn = SelectedRow->NumberOfUnits;
    
        CreateUnit(RequestedUnitClass, AmountToSpawn);
    }
    
    void AUnitContainer::CreateUnit(FName Classname, int Amount)
{
    // Determine class from row name
    FName RequestedUnitClass = Classname;

    // Spawn unit from Class
    FActorSpawnParameters SpawnInfo;
    RequestedUnitClass* Unit = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<RequestedUnitClass>(RequestedUnitClass::StaticClass(), SpawnLocation, SpawnRotation, SpawnInfo);
```

The Issue I’m having is that the variable RequestedUnitClass is not accepted as part of the arguments of the SpawnActor function. I'm still learning C++ and it seems to me that I am simply passing on the wrong data. I would like to use Row names as variables for class names but is that even possible? Like a row named SoldierType1 would spawn the class named SoldierType1 when parsed, with corresponding data (in this case, how many need to be spawned).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the function definition for `UWorld::SpawnActor` from the [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UWorld/SpawnActor/7/index.html),

```
template<class T>
T * SpawnActor
(
    UClass * Class,
    FVector const & Location,
    FRotator const & Rotation,
    const FActorSpawnParameters & SpawnParameters
)
```

the function does not take a parameter of type `FName` so you will have to replace that since the other three parameters seem to be correct. Also, your template parameter has to be an actual class and the first function parameter has to be of type `UClass*`. Right now, you have a variable of type `FName` for both which is incorrect. Therefore, you should replace your `TArray<FName> ClassNames` variable with a `TArray<TSubclassOf<AActor>> Classes` variable so that `RequestedUnitClass` is of type `UClass*`. You would have to modify your `ContainerDataTable->GetRowNames()` function to return a variable of type `TArray<TSubclassOf<AActor>>` as well for this to work.

When calling `SpawnActor`, you would use `AActor` for the template parameter. Note that I am only using `AActor` for the template parameter for both `TSubclassOf` and `SpawnActor` because I'm assuming that your array can refer to a variety of actor classes so I wanted to be as general as possible. Then for the `UClass*` parameter that the `SpawnActor` function takes, `RequestedUnitClass` should now work. Since I'm assuming that you don't want each actor spawned to be a general `AActor` all the time, you can cast the result to a a specific class after spawning the actor, but I will leave that up to you.

```
AActor* Unit = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AActor>(RequestedUnitClass, SpawnLocation, SpawnRotation, SpawnInfo);
...
// do some IsA class checks to figure out which class to cast the actor to
```